# swift error : Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>?' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>?'

Tags: ios, c, swift, pointers, unsafemutablepointer

I am working on **Xcode 10 iOS project**.
I am trying to call a C language function from Swift which takes pointer as parameter.

c function is as follows,

**Compress.h** file

```
short* Decompress(int *dataIn, int channelNum,int sample_cnt,long packet_cnt) ;
```

I am trying to call this method from **MyClassfile.swift**

Expected inputs from xcode is as follows

```
  var dataOut = Decompress(dataIn: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>!, channelNum: Int32, sample_cnt: Int32, packet_cnt: Int)
```

As the input for the first parameter is of type optional as "**UnsafeMutablePointer< Int32>!**"

I tried to convert the array to UnsafeMutablePointer type

the code is as follows,

```
var uint32PktArray = [UInt32]()

for index in stride(from: 0, to: somebuffer.count, by: 4){
          //doing some functionality here
          uint32PktArray.append(value)
}

          let uint32Pointer : UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>? = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>.allocate(capacity: uint32PktArray.count)
            uint32Pointer!.initialize(from: &uint32PktArray, count: uint32PktArray.count)

          print(type(of: uint32Pointer))// returns UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>?
```

but the input param requires an optional type, and the method is called as below

```
 var dataOut = Decompress(uint32Pointer,0, Int32(compHeaderECG0.smpl_cnt), Int(compHeaderECG0.pkt_cnt))
                print(dataOut)
```

while compiling I am getting an error for the above code, **"Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer?' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer?'"**

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Let me know if any clarity is required

Comment: <UInt32> and <Int32> are different types. Have you resolved that issue first?

Comment: yes let me try to fix that first

Comment: Thanks CodeBender fix it